# Regular Expression in php, extracting string between tags and replace it

Tags: php, expression

I have the following HTML and what I want is to extract the string between two tags and replace another string with the one that was extracted.
Here is an example:

```
<p>|something=to remember:yes: no</p>
<p><A:keyword term="to remember, yes no" /></p>
```

I have built something like this but I do not know whether regular expressions really help me here?

```
<[p]\>(.*)<\/p>
```

Comment: well, what happened when you tested it? This sounds like potentially a good use case for regular expressions, depending on the complexity of the document, or you could try to use a HTML DOM parser

Comment: Use `?` after `.*` so that the `*` is non-greedy. `<p\>(.*?)<\/p>`

Comment: does [DomDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) more efficient to parse HTML ? (if well formed of course).
With xpath you can easily get all **p** tags

Comment: You should consider reading **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)** before comitting too much resources into regex-based HTML parsers.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
I solved my problem by using

```
something==([A-Za-z]*)\s([A-Za-z]*),\s([A-Za-z]*)\s([A-Za-z]*)
```

as a static input and then everything after it was treated with regex and grouping.
With that solution I did solve my problem.